# Debian, Apache and conf-enabled

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, configuration

If conf-enabled configs contain Alias directives and Directory sections, to which VHost do they apply - to all ones in sites-enabled or to the default (first) one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives are applied to the Virtualhost directive in which they are defined or the global config if they arent inside one.

To view config precedence you can execute:

```
# apache2ctl -S
```